# Stuck with old controller in WebView after InAppWebView update

Tags: flutter, webview

[**THE PROBLEM**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77676709/22005920)

Stuck with old controller in InAppWebView after update! Tried everything, zero luck. Anyone know how to fix?